# Python 3: Get index names associated with the values in a certain column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get a list of the corresponding index names of 500,000 values out of 2,000,000 entries in a pandas dataframe which are located in a specific column names "entity_id" (out of 1000+ columns). My solution has been the following code:

```
    index_names_list= []
    for id in id_dataframe:
         index_names_list.append(full_data[full_data['entity_id'] == id ].index.values)
```

However, this runs very very slow. Can anyone suggest a better and more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: `full_data[full_data['entity_id'].isin(id_dataframe)].index.tolist()` Try this.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example including sample output of the desired results so we can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
full_data.loc[full_data['entity_id'].isin(id_dataframe),:].index.tolist()
```